# Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland Freezes

Tags: freeze, wayland

I installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Now I can't use in wayland. After booting up it works fine but after using the os for some minutes everything freezes and the OS become unresponsive. I faced the same problem with wayland 41 and I was expecting that this is fixed in wayland 42 but the same happens in this as well.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: Depending on your graphics card, Wayland my not yet fully cut it for you. Just stay a little longer on Xorg then: it is still available.

Comment: I have 8th gen core i7 intel, I see that this problem is common with nvidia gpu I don't have one. So I don't expect this on my laptop .

Comment: I have the same issue with Intel graphics (7th gen Core i7), while I did not have such a problem in previous Ubuntu versions (including 21.10).