# How to understand Ubuntu 22.04.1 freeze syslog?

Tags: kernel, freeze

I have run `cat /var/log/syslog` after my Ubuntu desktop froze and necessitated a forced power button reboot of the system. I'm curious if anyone else can make sense of what could have happened here?

```
Oct 13 16:00:47 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24640.886205] nvme 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Oct 13 16:00:47 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24640.886207] nvme 0000:03:00.0:   device [1cc1:5350] error status/mask=00000080/0000e000
Oct 13 16:00:47 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24640.886209] nvme 0000:03:00.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N gnome-shell[4482]: (../src/backends/native/meta-onscreen-native.c:595):import_shared_framebuffer: runtime check failed: (secondary_gpu_state->import_status == META_SHARED_FRAMEBUFFER_IMPORT_STATUS_NONE)
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N gnome-shell[4482]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742031] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:1:859ffffb, in gnome-shell [4482]
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742433] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742641] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] gnome-shell[4482] context reset due to GPU hang
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742681] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0xdead000000000108: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742691] CPU: 10 PID: 395400 Comm: kworker/10:1 Tainted: P        W  OE     5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742693] Hardware name: _COM1_ NBINF-O5-12R5N/GM5AGE0, BIOS N.1.07COM02 06/09/2022
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742694] Workqueue: events ttm_device_delayed_workqueue [ttm]
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742701] RIP: 0010:ttm_bo_delayed_delete+0x8b/0x230 [ttm]
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742705] Code: 08 00 00 48 3b 45 b8 0f 84 e1 00 00 00 4c 8b bb 18 08 00 00 48 8d 4d c0 49 8b 17 49 8b 47 08 4d 8d b7 70 fe ff ff 4d 8d 6f d0 <48> 89 42 08 48 89 10 48 8b 45 c8 4c 89 7d c8 49 89 0f 49 89 47 08
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742706] RSP: 0000:ffffa63222acfe08 EFLAGS: 00010216
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742708] RAX: dead000000000122 RBX: ffff8b675d6646f0 RCX: ffffa63222acfe18
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742709] RDX: dead000000000100 RSI: 529cc2c83a8e7c5d RDI: ffff8b675d664f00
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742710] RBP: ffffa63222acfe58 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffffbba39140
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742711] R10: ffff8b6e3fa38400 R11: dead000000000100 R12: ffff8b675d664f00
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742712] R13: ffff8b6e3fa38560 R14: ffff8b6e3fa38400 R15: ffff8b6e3fa38590
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742713] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8b767f880000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742714] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742715] CR2: 000029eacac86000 CR3: 0000000171ba0002 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742716] PKRU: 55555554
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742717] Call Trace:
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742718]  <TASK>
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742725]  ttm_device_delayed_workqueue+0x1c/0x50 [ttm]
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742729]  process_one_work+0x228/0x3d0
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742732]  worker_thread+0x53/0x420
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742733]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742735]  kthread+0x127/0x150
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742737]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742739]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742742]  </TASK>
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742743] Modules linked in: ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_recent xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec intel_tcc_cooling snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep coretemp snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi iwlmvm snd_seq_midi_event btusb snd_rawmidi uvcvideo
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742780]  btrtl btbcm snd_seq joydev processor_thermal_device_pci btintel videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_device processor_thermal_device videobuf2_memops mei_hdcp mac80211 kvm bluetooth snd_timer processor_thermal_rfim essiv videobuf2_v4l2 ecdh_generic processor_thermal_mbox authenc intel_rapl_msr libarc4 rapl iwlwifi intel_cstate input_leds videobuf2_common ecc processor_thermal_rapl snd mei_me intel_rapl_common serio_raw ucsi_acpi pmt_telemetry asus_wmi typec_ucsi cfg80211 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch ee1004 mei pmt_class soundcore int340x_thermal_zone igen6_edac platform_profile typec ov13858 v4l2_fwnode v4l2_async videodev intel_hid mac_hid mc sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zzstd(O) zlua(O) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid i915 nouveau mxm_wmi
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742825]  i2c_algo_bit drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic cec rc_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd drm intel_lpss_pci i2c_hid_acpi nvme r8169 i2c_i801 ahci i2c_hid intel_lpss xhci_pci nvme_core i2c_smbus realtek idma64 libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_pmt wmi hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.742842] ---[ end trace 30aa0b9b5381b0ff ]---
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.750990] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_62.0.3.bin version 62.0 submission:enabled
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.750995] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC SLPC: enabled
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.750997] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9 authenticated:yes
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N firefox_firefox.desktop[18776]: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863577] RIP: 0010:ttm_bo_delayed_delete+0x8b/0x230 [ttm]
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863589] Code: 08 00 00 48 3b 45 b8 0f 84 e1 00 00 00 4c 8b bb 18 08 00 00 48 8d 4d c0 49 8b 17 49 8b 47 08 4d 8d b7 70 fe ff ff 4d 8d 6f d0 <48> 89 42 08 48 89 10 48 8b 45 c8 4c 89 7d c8 49 89 0f 49 89 47 08
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863591] RSP: 0000:ffffa63222acfe08 EFLAGS: 00010216
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863593] RAX: dead000000000122 RBX: ffff8b675d6646f0 RCX: ffffa63222acfe18
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863594] RDX: dead000000000100 RSI: 529cc2c83a8e7c5d RDI: ffff8b675d664f00
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863595] RBP: ffffa63222acfe58 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffffbba39140
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863596] R10: ffff8b6e3fa38400 R11: dead000000000100 R12: ffff8b675d664f00
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863596] R13: ffff8b6e3fa38560 R14: ffff8b6e3fa38400 R15: ffff8b6e3fa38590
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863597] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8b767f880000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863599] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863600] CR2: 000029eacac86000 CR3: 0000000171ba0002 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Oct 13 16:02:38 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24751.863601] PKRU: 55555554
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885693] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 26s! [gnome-shell:4482]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885699] Modules linked in: ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_recent xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec intel_tcc_cooling snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep coretemp snd_pcm kvm_intel snd_seq_midi iwlmvm snd_seq_midi_event btusb snd_rawmidi uvcvideo
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885730]  btrtl btbcm snd_seq joydev processor_thermal_device_pci btintel videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_device processor_thermal_device videobuf2_memops mei_hdcp mac80211 kvm bluetooth snd_timer processor_thermal_rfim essiv videobuf2_v4l2 ecdh_generic processor_thermal_mbox authenc intel_rapl_msr libarc4 rapl iwlwifi intel_cstate input_leds videobuf2_common ecc processor_thermal_rapl snd mei_me intel_rapl_common serio_raw ucsi_acpi pmt_telemetry asus_wmi typec_ucsi cfg80211 wmi_bmof hid_multitouch ee1004 mei pmt_class soundcore int340x_thermal_zone igen6_edac platform_profile typec ov13858 v4l2_fwnode v4l2_async videodev intel_hid mac_hid mc sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zzstd(O) zlua(O) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid i915 nouveau mxm_wmi
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885768]  i2c_algo_bit drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic cec rc_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd drm intel_lpss_pci i2c_hid_acpi nvme r8169 i2c_i801 ahci i2c_hid intel_lpss xhci_pci nvme_core i2c_smbus realtek idma64 libahci xhci_pci_renesas intel_pmt wmi hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885784] CPU: 4 PID: 4482 Comm: gnome-shell Tainted: P      D W  OE     5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885787] Hardware name: _COM1_ NBINF-O5-12R5N/GM5AGE0, BIOS N.1.07COM02 06/09/2022
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885788] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath.part.0+0x51/0x200
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885793] Code: 2b 08 0f 92 c2 8b 03 0f b6 d2 c1 e2 08 30 e4 09 d0 a9 00 01 ff ff 0f 85 2a 01 00 00 85 c0 74 0e 8b 03 84 c0 74 08 f3 90 8b 03 <84> c0 75 f8 b8 01 00 00 00 66 89 03 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885794] RSP: 0018:ffffa631ce10bb68 EFLAGS: 00000202
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885795] RAX: 0000000000000101 RBX: ffff8b675d664f00 RCX: 0000000000000018
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885796] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8b675d664f00
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885797] RBP: ffffa631ce10bb90 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000000
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885798] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 00000000000d0000 R12: ffff8b6d4f18eac0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885799] R13: ffff8b6742f7b0d0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8b68a240d640
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885800] FS:  00007f847819f5c0(0000) GS:ffff8b767f700000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885801] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885802] CR2: 00007fed76b00a00 CR3: 0000000171ba0002 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885803] PKRU: 55555554
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885803] Call Trace:
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885804]  <TASK>
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885807]  native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x2c/0x40
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885809]  _raw_spin_lock+0x22/0x30
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885812]  nouveau_gem_object_close+0x167/0x1e0 [nouveau]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885861]  drm_gem_object_release_handle+0x2d/0x80 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885874]  drm_gem_handle_delete+0x59/0xa0 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885884]  ? drm_mode_destroy_dumb+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885897]  drm_gem_dumb_destroy+0x10/0x20 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885906]  drm_mode_destroy_dumb_ioctl+0x3b/0x50 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885918]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb0/0x100 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885927]  drm_ioctl+0x268/0x4b0 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885937]  ? drm_mode_destroy_dumb+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885948]  ? rseq_ip_fixup+0x72/0x170
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885950]  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x66/0xc0 [nouveau]
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885986]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x92/0xd0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885988]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885990]  ? handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885992]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1e7/0x670
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885994]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885996]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885997]  ? irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.885999]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x170
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886000]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886002] RIP: 0033:0x7f847d540aff
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886003] Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <41> 89 c0 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1f 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886004] RSP: 002b:00007fff1d447220 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886006] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff1d4472b4 RCX: 00007f847d540aff
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886006] RDX: 00007fff1d4472b4 RSI: 00000000c00464b4 RDI: 0000000000000075
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886007] RBP: 00000000c00464b4 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007fff1d447340
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886008] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000560507610e08
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886008] R13: 0000000000000075 R14: 000056050e4ef270 R15: 000056050a488f10
Oct 13 16:03:02 peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N kernel: [24775.886010]  </TASK>
```

I had some other trouble like [Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland Freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404830/ubuntu-22-04-wayland-freezes) earlier though this one seems different. In case it helps:

```
peter@peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N:~$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       4.7Gi        56Gi       667Mi       1.7Gi        56Gi
Swap:          2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
peter@peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
peter@peter-NBINF-O5-12R5N:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size        Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   2097148     0   -2
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you using display scaling? Maybe 125% or 150%? Is this on a 12th Gen Intel CPU? 

Comment: Forced to use power button?  So you're saying you couldn't use SysRq commands direct to kernel to reboot/shutdown safely?  ie. your issue is kernel panic?   (ie. *anything on user level, including all GUI/terminal functions (ie. screen/terminal completely stuck) will not prevent the kernel accepting commands directly*)

Comment: Default display scaling. Yes keyboard and mouse were completely unresponsive, though I did not think to try the Ctrl + Alt + F6 and Ctrl + Alt + F2 keys - they are a very well hidden “feature” 

Comment: Yep Settings > About > Processor is showing 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700H x 20

Comment: I mentioned the SysRq commands which bypass any stuck gui/display issue & go direct to the kernel. If unsure what they are, given they aren't a Ubuntu feature - but a kernel function, grab a phone & search "*magic sysrq*" and the wikipedia article is usually near the top. Using them is almost certainly guaranteed to work (*they won't work if you have a kernel panic, and having that is extremely useful diagnostic detail!*) if you have a real keyboard (*thus no good on an android phone which requires the working GUI for onscreen keyboard to work! let alone no SysRq exists there*)

Comment: do note:  SysRq was always written on the front side of the key, so many modern keyboards (*which are very then thus writing on the front face wouldn't be visible anyway*) still have the function available, but the key label isn't usually seen on modern laptops; it's still present though, but some require an extra Fn key to be used.  If you look at a real keyboard (*especially older & not chiclet*) you can see where it's located - it's the same key on modern dell/hp/lenovo/etc even if not marked. (*a quick look at a sony vaoi & I can see key to use, on samsung nothing seen but easy to guess*)

Comment: Took me a while to find a keyboard with a Sys Rq key on it (the laptop does not have it) and further it looks like I'd need to enable it as Ubuntu now just basically calls Print Screen, including with the Alt + Prt Scr, super and Fn keys so I'm out of ideas on actually triggering this magical Sys Rq: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911522/how-can-i-enable-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-ubuntu-desktop